# Node.js app gives 504 on Plesk-Onyx

Tags: node.js, plesk, plesk-onyx

I have Node.js/Postgres app (tested and worked on different servers without an issue). When I try to run this app via Plesk's Node.js extension, the domain becomes inaccessible and I get 504 Gateway Time-out error.

Additionally, when I run the "start" script, Plesk panel output freezes and the only way to get an output is to run "killall node" command on SSH. After killing the node, I get the expected output without any errors.

All the dependencies are installed without any issue. Any idea what causes the problem and what is the solution?